# Split MySQL table text values to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have table :

```
id | room_type     | room_size
1  | a;b;c         | 5;7;12   
2  | b;c;d;f       | 8;2;4
3  | b;c;d;f;g;h   | 6;4;5;6;7;2;9
```

i want output like this :

```
id | name    | room_size
1  | a       | 5
1  | b       | 7
1  | c       | 12
2  | b       | 8
2  | c       | 2
2  | d       | 4
2  | f       | NULL
3  | b       | 6
3  | c       | 4
3  | d       | 5
3  | f       | 6
3  | g       | 7
3  | h       | 2
```

Note: in (id) 2, it is the room_size count is less by 1. In (id) 3, the room_size is more by 1

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: Let this be a lesson to design your database properly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store comma separated lists of values. (This doesn't mean to use semicolons in place of commas.)

**SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming** -- Bill Karwin, Chapter 2

Available at Amazon and other fine booksellers.

[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

---

For a finite number of values, we can split those out into separate rows

(Replace inline view `t` with your table)

```
SELECT t.id
     , i.n
     , NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( t.room_type ,';;'),';',i.n),';',-1),'') AS room_type_n
     , NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( t.room_size ,';;'),';',i.n),';',-1),'') AS room_size_n
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id, 'a;b;c' AS room_type, '5;7;12'  AS room_size
         UNION ALL SELECT 2,'b;c;d;f','8;2;4'
         UNION ALL SELECT 3,'b;c;d;f;g;h','6;4;5;6;7;2;9'
       ) t
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS n
         UNION ALL SELECT 2
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5
         UNION ALL SELECT 6
         UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 8
         UNION ALL SELECT 9
       ) i 
HAVING NOT ( room_type_n <=> NULL )
 ORDER BY t.id, i.n
```

Returns:

```
 id    n  room_type_n  room_size_n
---  ---  -----------  -----------
  1    1  a            5
  1    2  b            7
  1    3  c            12
  2    1  b            8
  2    2  c            2
  2    3  d            4
  2    4  f            (NULL)
  3    1  b            6
  3    2  c            4
  3    3  d            5
  3    4  f            6
  3    5  g            7
  3    6  h            2
```

Inline view `i` should be extended to the finite, maximum number of values we expect to extract: `UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The table is big not just 1,2 and 3 IDs.

Comment: This part I can not understand, as I need to apply the query to a different table with much records. 

  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id, 'a;b;c' AS room_type, '5;7;12'  AS room_size
         UNION ALL SELECT 2,'b;c;d;f','8;2;4'
         UNION ALL SELECT 3,'b;c;d;f;g;h','6;4;5;6;7;2;9'
       ) t

Comment: just replace the inline view (the query between the parens before the `t`) with a table reference.   Change this  "**`FROM  ( SELECT 1 ... ) t`**"  to "**`FROM mytable t`**"